# $.ajax success callback not triggerede in IE11 -> xhr.status = 0 responseText is empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

Ok, so I'm basically using ajax to import my json data.

This works perfectly in chrome and firefox, but for some reason **not in Internet Explorer 11** (haven't checked earlier versions).

this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'data.json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType:'json',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: jsonParser,
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log(xhr.status);
            }

        });
```

The xhr status is 0, which is "responseText is empty". Don't really know what that means, but it might be useful. The problem is that the **success callback isn't called in internet explorer**. Been looking for answers for hours, but I still have no idea, what is wrong :( I'm doing everything locally from my own harddrive, but I have been testing via wamp-server as well.

I hope some one here knows the answer. Kind regards!

EDIT: For some reason it worked when I put it online. So I guess sometimes wamp is not enough to be sure. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: How do you know that the success callback isn't getting called? What steps have you taken to ensure that it isn't getting called?

Comment: Why are you using contentType application/json with type GET? Why are you using async false?

Comment: *"I'm doing everything locally from my own harddrive, but I have been testing via wamp-server as well"* skip testing it locally and always test via a server.

Comment: If you point the browser directly to your json file, what do you get?

Comment: I know, since the stuff happening in the callback function is not happening.

Comment: im not really using async or contenttype. Doesnt make a difference whether they are there or not. This is not the issue.